# Dart: Use non-constant value as default constructor parameter

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I would like to use FirebaseAuth.instance (a non-constant value) as a default parameter in a constructor.

I have this class:

```
class MailAuth {
  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  MailAuth();

  // methods using firebaseAuth
}
```

Now I want to unit-test this class, so I want to mock `firebaseAuth` and inject the mock in the constructor. It should be a named parameter with the default value of `FirebaseAuth.instance`. I tried something like this:

```
class MailAuth {
  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

  MailAuth({this.firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance});

  // methods using firebaseAuth 
}
```

But this doesn't work because `FirebaseAuth.instance` is not a constant.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the accepted answer works, you don't really have to "Use a *null* value as sign to use your default value".

With *sound null safety*, you might not want to make your instance variable of nullable type (`final FirebaseAuth? firebaseAuth`) for several reasons.

Instead of starting with *null* or having a *nullable type*(?), just declare your instance variable as *late*, instead of *final*, indicating that you do want to initialise it, ensuring you initialise it in the constructor with a default value if none is passed in invocation.

So now you will get:

```
class MailAuth {
  late FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

  MailAuth({firebaseAuth}) {
    this.firebaseAuth = this.firebaseAuth ?? FirebaseAuth.instance;
  }

  // methods using firebaseAuth 
}
```

Comment: The parameter is untyped, so it has type `dynamic`. The class field is not longer final, and is even late (unnecessarily). You should initialize the variable in the initializer list, and make it final.

Comment: okay, yes. I see that late is in fact unnecessary. Initialising the variable in the constructor initialiser list does make more sense.

Answer (score 7):

Use a `null` value as sign to use your default value:

```dart
 MailAuth({FirebaseAuth? firebaseAuth}) 
    : firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

This initializes the variable with the parameter if the parameter is non-null, otherwise it uses the "default" singleton instance instead.

(Updated for null safety. This still works, and the instance variable isn't non-nullable. Only the constructor parameter is nullable.)